# std::accumulate declaration before and after gcc 5.4

Tags: c++, gcc

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), `std::accumulate` lives in `<numeric>`, however, when I am compiling using gcc 5.4:

```
$gcc --version | grep gcc
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I find that it happily compiles if the only #include is `<algorithm>`. I can reproduce this [using gcc 5.3 on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/X446mq). The correct behavior is seen in [later versions](https://godbolt.org/z/DyOqFf) of gcc.

I am trying to migrate our development setup from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (gcc 5.4 to gcc 7.3), and developers keep making this mistake (including `<algorithm>` instead of `<numeric>`) and since gcc 5.4 doesn't complain, we don't notice it until I build with later versions of gcc. Eventually we will all be on 18.04, but in the meantime...

**Is there a way to make gcc 5.4 flag this as an error or warning?**

Comment: Generally, any header file can, itself, include any other header file. The only way to ensure portability is to explicitly include the correct header file. And, the only way to prevent gcc from successfully compiling this, is to rewrite its header files yourself.

Comment: I was hoping maybe it was some non-standard convention that had a flag or #define somewhere, but it turns out, `bits/stl_algo.h` includes `random` (which at some point includes `numeric`) while the later library implemenations include a new file (`bits/uniform_int_dist.h`) which doesn't include `numeric`. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: gcc has long historical reputation of being a high quality, standards-compliant, C++ compiler. The chances of gcc taking the "eh, we'll play fast and loose with standards by default, but have some optional switch that more closely follows the C++ specification" are slim, to none. Each subsequent version of gcc tends to closer follow the standard. As you've noticed here. This is not an option. If some part of gcc doesn't follow the standard, you're not going to find some option that will make it compliant.